# Not able to play mp4 video on Chrome Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I have download a sample 5Mb mp4 video  from http://www.sample-videos.com/ . I am not able to play video on chrome browser. I am using simple html5 video tag

But When I upload same video on facebook it is playing fine on chrome browser

What I've tried to do is:

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls> <source src="../Videos/5 Taara_HD.mp4"
type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: <video width="560" height="340" controls>
    <source src="../Videos/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4" type='video/mp4;>
</video>

Comment: This Video is working fine in IE10,Firefox browser .Issue is only with Chrome browser

Comment: You need a single quote instead a semicolon in type: `type='video/mp4'`

Comment: Allan Pereira It doesnt work there is some problem with codec of video Some mp4 videos are playing fine but  big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4 from website http://www.sample-videos.com/ doesnt work in chrome browser

Comment: Facebook transcodes the videos to reduce storage and bandwidth, and also to improve comatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1) if want to autoplay=>   add  `autoplay muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true";` else remove that, it will work fine in every browser.

2) Add `muted`

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls  autoplay muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" > <source src="../Videos/5 Taara_HD.mp4"
type='video/mp4'>
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```